# React Redux capture updated store state after updating database

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an issue similar to what is discussed here:  https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291

My issue is that I have a parent component that renders a child based on a state value in my redux store which is basically a list of transactions retrieved from my database.  The parent component passes these transactions to the child component.  The child component (a popup) updates the database using a dispatched action.  When I close my popup after updating my database, I then call another action to get the transactions again from the database so that I can rerender the parent with the new data.

My problem is that the action to get the transactions after saving, does not seem to update the state in my store until I leave the page and come back.  My assumption is that a rerender of my parent should extract the new state.

How should I be handling something like this?

Below is some sample code.  When handleRefresh is entered after my popup updates my data, I expect the parent component to be rerendered and for MonthView to display the updated data.  However, this does not happen until I leave the page by navigating to any other page and come back.

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import MonthView from './MonthView.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTransactions } from '../actions/actions.js';

  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.getTransactions(2016);

  }

 handleRefresh() {

    //call the action to update transactions state in my redux store
    this.props.getTransactions(2016);

    this.setState({ refreshView: true}, function () {});
  }

 render() {
    return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-12">
        <MonthView 
          transactions={this.props.storeTransactions.transactions} 
          selectedYear={this.props.storeTransactions.selectedYear} 
          onAddYear={this.handleAddYear} 
          onSubtractYear={this.handleSubtractYear} 
          onHandleGetDetail={this.handleGetDetail} 
        />
    </div>
    <div>
        <TransactionsPopupContainer 
            modalActive={this.state.detailPopup} 
            transactions={this.props.storePopupTransactions ? this.props.storePopupTransactions.popuptransactions : [] }
            selectedYear={this.props.storeTransactions.selectedYear} 
            category={this.popupCategory} 
            month={this.popupMonth}
            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
        />
    </div>
  </div>
    )

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  storeTransactions: state.storeTransactions
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTransactions})(MonthViewContainer);
```

MonthViewContainer

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import TransactionsPopupView from './TransactionsPopupView.js';
import { getPopupTransactions } from '../actions/actions.js';
import { saveTransactions } from '../actions/actions.js';

handleSave() {
    this.props.saveTransactions(this.editedTrans);
    this.props.onRefresh();
}

render() {

 if (this.props.transactions) {
            this.editedTrans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( this.props.transactions));
        } 

        return (
            <TransactionsPopupView 
                transactions={this.props.transactions}
                modalActive={this.props.modalActive} 
                onCategoryChange={this.handleCategoryChange}
                onNotesChange={this.handleNotesChange}
                savePopup={this.handleSave}
                handleRefreshParent={this.props.onRefresh}
            />
        );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {storePopupTransactions: state.storePopupTransactions,
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getPopupTransactions,saveTransactions})(TransactionsPopupContainer);
```

Actions

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_TRANSACTIONS = 'GET_TRANSACTIONS';

export function getTransactions(year) {

  console.log("gettransactions action entered");

 return function(dispatch) {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/transfilter?year=${year}&grouping=2`)
   .then(response => {
     console.log("response data in the gettransactions reducer: ", response.data);
     dispatch({
       type: GET_TRANSACTIONS,
       payload: response.data,
       selectedYear: year
     });
   })
   .catch((error) => {
   })
 }
}


export const SAVE_TRANSACTIONS = 'SAVE_TRANSACTIONS';

export function saveTransactions(transUpdate) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/updateTransactions', transUpdate)
   .then(response => {
     dispatch({
       type: SAVE_TRANSACTIONS,
       payload: response.data,
     });
   })
   .catch((error) => {
   })
  }
}
```

Reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import {GET_TRANSACTIONS } from '../actions/actions.js'
import {SAVE_TRANSACTIONS } from '../actions/actions.js'

const INITIAL_STATE = { 
  defaultYear: 2018, 
  transactions: [], 
  searchMode: false
};

function get_transactions(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  console.log("this is in the reducer: get_transactions");
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_TRANSACTIONS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        transactions: action.payload,
        selectedYear: action.selectedYear
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


const SAVE_TRANSACTIONS_INITIAL_STATE = { saveResult: []}

function save_transactions(state = SAVE_TRANSACTIONS_INITIAL_STATE,action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case SAVE_TRANSACTIONS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        saveResult: action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const SAVE_TRANSACTIONS_INITIAL_STATE = { saveResult: []}

function save_transactions(state = SAVE_TRANSACTIONS_INITIAL_STATE,action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case SAVE_TRANSACTIONS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        saveResult: action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: are any of these components actually being [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)ed to the store?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  All of them are connected. I'll add code to show that.

Comment: You should also add the code for your MonthView component

Comment: Show the action and reducer code too

Comment: I added it.  The views are really just that and don't have any code, just html.  All the logic is in the containers.  The transactionpopup container is where the save occurs for the popup before returning to the parent.

Comment: Do you have redux dev tools installed to make sure your store looks like you would expect?  Unless all the reducers you show are different files, it looks like you're resetting your transactions and such in the store to { saveResult: whatever }.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I am setting up redux dev tools to look into it. I've actually now separated my reducers to all be separate files instead of one file, but the issue persists.

Comment: @mindlis I've actually create another related question but that is strictly conceptual and gives more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724477