# React Redux store state update process after saving to database

Tags: reactjs, redux

My questions is a conceptual one and based on the issue outlined in this post:  [React Redux capture updated store state after updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695120).  I don't think any code is needed to understand or be able to answer it.  But if not it is at the link above.

I think I might have missed a small detail about the react/redux state update process following an action that changes the back-end data that a state variable reflects. My question is: When I dispatch a save action, should I then also be dispatching a request to update any state that depends on that underlying data?

So for example, right now the way I'm thinking about it and implementing my code is as follows:

1. app starts and `ParentComponent` loads and dispatches `GET_DATA` on componentDidMount which initializes state variable `data` which is reflected on `ParentComponent` in a table
2. when a link is clicked on `ParentComponent`, `ParentComponent` renders `ChildComponent` which is a react-modal popup that displays elements of `data` so it can be updated
3. there is and `Save and Close` button on ChildComponent; when you click the button, `SAVE_DATA` is dispatched and the changes to `data` that are made on `ChildComponent` get saved to the database
4. THIS is where my question arises... at this point should I also be calling `GET_DATA` to dispatch the process of "refreshing" `data` in my state?  Would this be the right way to handle saving data to a database when using redux so that all components that rely on `data` get updated?

Note: What I'm currently doing is that after step 3, I am simply triggering a refresh function in `ParentComponent` so that it rerenders and hence reflects `data` in state.  The epiphany I just had is that there is no way for `data` in state to reflect the new saved data because `GET_DATA` has not been dispatched after saving and rerendering the component does not trigger `GET_DATA`.

Are my assumptions correct?  Should I be calling `GET_DATA` somewhere else in my ParentComponent like `ComponentWillReceiveProps`?  The issue I had here is that maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it triggers an endless loop.  Somehow though I feel that is the only place where I can address my need to dispatch `GET_DATA` after the local `ParentComponent` state is changed by setting `refresh` (a `ParentComponent` state variable) to `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it would benefit you to refactor your actions a bit to take advantage of the action/middleware/reducer pattern.

You would have an action `GET_TRANSACTIONS`, that would take your year param.  Your `transactionsMiddleware` would respond to the `GET_TRANSACTIONS` action by making your fetch request and would dispatch `GET_TRANSACTIONS_SUCCESS` with the respond data on success.  You `transactions` reducer would then process the data into your store.

```
actions
export const getTransactions = year => {
  return {
    type: "GET_TRANSACTIONS",
    year
  };
};

export const getTransactionsSuccess = payload => {
  return {
    type: "GET_TRANSACTIONS_SUCCESS",
    payload
  };
};

middleware
function getTransactions(year) {
  fetch().then(response => dispatch(actions.getTransactionsSuccess(response.data));
}

reducer
const getTransactionsSuccess = (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, newStuffFromActionPayload);
}
```

You would also have an action `SAVE_TRANSACTIONS`, which would be what your button would dispatch, along with the data to save.  Your `transactionsMiddleware` would respond to the action by dispatching the update request.  Your API would return the data from the updated record.

This is where you would have the middleware dispatch a follow-up action.  It could be your `getTransactions` action, but it'd be even better to dispatch an action that your reducer would respond to by merging in the new data to your store.

```
actions
export const updateTransaction = payload => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_TRANSACTION",
    payload
  };
};

export const updateTransactionSuccess = payload => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS",
    payload
  };
};

middleware
function updateTransaction(transUpdate) {
  fetch().then(response => dispatch(actions.updateTransactionSuccess(response.data))
}

reducer
const updateTransactionSuccess = (state, action) => {
  find the record in the state, update it with data from action.payload
  return Object.assign({}, state, updatedRecord);
}
```

If everything is set up correctly, it should trigger an update on your parent when it detects the change in the store.  You avoid making two API calls for every save as well.

Comment: Apologies for the super long answer, I hope it at least helps.  If you keep your actions the same way as they are now, you should be able to implement the same idea with chaining actions.

Comment: Beautiful!! This is what I had already started doing based on my research on the official redux site with the todos sample app that implements the middleware setup.  I've already setup my get_transactions to use the middleware setup and just need to do the same with my save.  I'm confident it will work.  I asked a similar question like over a year ago and never got a response.  But I feel this is a basic aspect of react redux that I just had thought about the wrong way.  Thanks for confirming! I'll come back and check answer once I setup and test everything.

Comment: @mindlies I setup and tested different options. 1. in my save transactions middleware I dispatch the `getTransactions`.  That worked perfect and does everything I want. 2. As you suggested do it all in my inital `updateTransactions` call.  Here I have an issue because it seems as though redux combine reducers keeps a separate state tree for each reducer.  Is my assumption correct? In my `updateTransactions` middleware I am setting state to the new values, but my component is bound to the state in the `getTransactions` reducer.  This is an aspect of combine reducer I wasn't aware of.

Comment: That's right, but you should put your reducer action for `updateTransactions` in the same file as your other transaction reducer functions. Both are doing something to the transactions in your store.

Comment: Indeed all my actions are in the same file.  It is only my reducers that are separated into separate files.  So would putting all my reducers in the same file allow me to share the same state across all the reducers?  I'm assuming yes.  If so, is there any convention that suggests not doing this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I'm suggesting. Put all your transaction reducer functions into one file and use a case to call the right one based on the action type

Comment: Perfect. That's how I had it initially setup, but I read a couple of posts by Gaearon which suggested separating things out... `https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/601` I'll revert to how I had it.

Comment: @mo_maat, were you able to sort it out?

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Just running into a little hurdle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738874